# Make this query more efficient

Tags: php, laravel

I'm terrible at writing queries that are dealing with large datasets. I wanted to take a stab at Laravel and see what I can come up with. Is there a better way to write this query and output the results?

**Code**

```
$visitors = DB::table('visitors')
            ->where('id_client',1)
            ->select('id', 'ip', DB::raw('count(*) as total'), 'date', 'city', 'region')
            ->groupBy('ip')
            ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
            ->simplePaginate(25);
```

**Results**

```
@foreach($visitors as $visitor)
               <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{$visitor->id}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (date('F d, Y', strtotime($visitor->date)) === date('F d, Y'))
                                Today
                            @else
                                {{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($visitor->date)) }}
                            @endif  
                        </td> 
                        <td>
                            {{$visitor-total}}
                        </td>                       
                        <td>
                            {{$visitor->city}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{$visitor->region}}
                        </td>
                 </tr>
          @endforeach

          {!! $visitors->render() !!}
```

Also, I get the error `Use of undefined constant total - assumed 'total'` when I try to load the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: well since it doesn't even work, "more" efficient would be just working

Comment: `{$visitor-total}}` syntax error, missing the `>` for accessor methods off of objects. Also, what's wrong with the query that you have? Is it slow? Does it not produce the desired results?

Comment: You get that error because of a typo: {{$visitor-total}} should be {{$visitor->total}}

Comment: You might also wanna read the `Note: Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel.`  [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#basic-usage)

Comment: is problem : {{$visitor-total}} -> {{$visitor->total}} ?

Comment: No amount of framework code will make up for a semantic in your code, nor will it help with an innefficient database schema. Go read some of the many questions about query tuning and see if you can spot a pattern between the ones which have been upvoted and answered compared to the ones which have been closed.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks good as long as it does what you need.

If your query runs too slow, maybe you can add an index to your 'id_client' column to make the search faster (if you don't have it already of course).